# Facts, References, **OR** Specific Expertise

Tags: discussion, support

I do not understand what the problem is with my [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) question: [What's your favorite alternative tuning and why? [closed]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/9574/1344).

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Example songs are facts. Why it's your favorite is specific expertise. The word *OR* means only one of these is needed.

Debate?!! Is somebody gonna disagree about What's your favorite?

Arguments?!! While I agree that *debate* is bad, [*arguments*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument) are good. *Why* solicits (good) arguments.

Polling? Well, yeah. That's the territory. Same with extended discussion.

---

Alternate Tunings is precisely the sort of topic that needs this kind of treatment. Sure you can find lists of tunings and songs out there. But when you're just beginning to explore these things, a little guidance or endorsement is nice.

Comment: Seriously??? "While I agree that debate is bad, arguments are good". I would say its the complete opposite

Comment: Debates are built around facts and attempt to persuade. Arguments are more often built around someones personal view regardless of whether reason has been applied. So debate is far more constructive than arguments. I'd also advise you to learn from various sources and not believe everything wikipedia tells you. Here's a good [explaination](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47064/whats-the-difference-between-debate-and-argument) since you like links so much

Comment: http://youtu.be/kQFKtI6gn9Y?t=2m2s

Comment: Debate is about winning against an opponent (using facts if possible, fallacy if necessary). Argument is about reasoning.

Comment: @Mick Thanks. I *do* like links. I've weighed-in on that melée, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polling is still polling, even if you want the opinions to be backed up by facts and/or references and/or expertise.  Asking what people's favorites are is never on-topic no matter what objective evidence you tell answerers to include.

I also disagree that it takes any expertise to pick a favorite.  "I like it a lot" is a perfectly valid reason to have a favorite.

Also important is that it's impossible to get people to vote on the answers "properly" — it's a popularity contest.  If a tuning isn't someone's favorite they will vote it down and upvote the one they like, instead of promoting good answers.

Comment: Yes.  Alternate tunings are on-topic; it's the "what's your favorite X?" style of question that's a bad fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew and @Monica. I've tried address your concerns.