# Good Poll/Bad Poll -- Lesson to learn?

Tags: discussion

I think I've tripped over a line between this [good question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/what-are-the-various-ways-of-vocalizing-rhythmic-figures) and this [bad question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9574/whats-the-most-useful-alternate-tuning-and-why). And I'm wondering what is the lesson here?

The word "favorite" is a dead buzzkill. Pragmatic (but vague) adjectives are: useful, interesting, rare, um, useful?

What are the precise boundaries (*a posteriori*) in this territory?

**Bonus question.** Am I making too much fuss over this? We're all still friends, right?

Comment: Was the "care to explain?" remark the first mistake? Or looting the area51 archive at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in beta, the dividing line is still being defined so the closer you get to the ontopic/offtopic/objective/subjective line, the more chance someone will find it off topic -

From experience on other sites, keeping things objective does really help. Some folks will see anything 'not site focused' as worthy of a downvote. Others will be very rigid with the rules (I know I have on occasion - on this site and others)

There is still value in asking the question if you think it is just on the right side of the line, but if you have doubts, asking in meta should always help.

In terms of being emotional - better if you can step away from the personal involvement, sure, but hey - everyone does that sort of thing occasionally, so I wouldn't take it to heart.

Answer (score 2):

Well here's what I've come up with.

With the vocalizing rhythms question, it's a poll and a list, BUT it's material that may or may not be available elsewhere collected together in this manner. It's almost *so general* that it's hard to find because specific instances may go by so many different names.

With the alternate tunings, despite my contrived little story, it really is information that's abundantly available elsewhere. So hosting a new poll here doesn't really *add to the content of the web*.

I know [I got a little emotional](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/1344). And while I think I refrained from saying anything that I need to regret, my attitude was not exemplary. And that's something I can learn from all this.